# embedding javascript in templates using wiselinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, wiselinks

I'm using Wiselinks in my Rails app but as I add more view templates I am running into trouble getting JavaScript in those templates to run when I want.

Naively, what I want to do is this:

**Template**

```
....
- content_for :subscript do
    :javascript
        $(function() {
            // do stuff
        }
```

The `content_for :subscript` puts the js at the bottom of the document so it loads quickly for regular http requests.

The `$(function() { ... }` is to wait until the DOM is loaded before executing the inner js.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for two reasons:

1. The `content_for` line is going to be ignored by wiselinks requests since it's not rendering into a layout, it's just rendering the template.
2. The `$(function() { ... }` bit will only get evaluated the jQuery `ready` event is fired and it doesn't get fired on wiselinks requests.

I can address the first issue by defining a helper method `wise_content_for` that works like content_for except it returns its contents to render directly on the page for wiselinks requests. Now I can do the following:

```
= wise_content_for :subscript do
    ...
```

I can address the second issue by triggering `page:always` on the first DOM load and then wrapping my js code in that:

**Layout**

```
...
:javascript
    $(function() {
        wiselinks = new Wiselinks($('#wiselinks-container'));
        $(document).trigger('page:always')
    }
...
```

**Template**

```
= wise_content_for :subscript do
    :javascript
        $(document).on('page:always', function() {
            // do stuff
        }
```

HOWEVER... `// do stuff` will now be executed on EVERY wiselinks request after its first called. This is undesirable for some code, so I'm looking for a way to make sure that js code for each template is only executed when that template is rendered.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

I'm looking for a solution that will allow other developers working on this code to NOT have to worry about how each template will work when its rendered normally vs with wiselinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

I simply call each function defined in a the array `Boundless.PageCallbacks` after the first page load and after each wiselinks request completes. The array is cleared at the start of each wiselinks request so only code pushed onto the array during the current request gets executed each time.

**Layout**

```
:javascript

  function call_page_callbacks(){
    _.each(Boundless.PageCallbacks, function(callback){ callback(); }
  }

  $(function() {
    new Wiselinks($('#wiselinks-container'));

    $(document).off('page:loading').on('page:loading', function(){
      Boundless.PageCallbacks = [];
    });

    $(document).off('page:always').on('page:always', call_page_callbacks);

    call_page_callbacks();
  }
```

**Templates and Partials**

```
= wise_content_for :javascripts do

  :javascript

    Boundless.PageCallbacks.push(function() {
      // do stuff
    });
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def wise_content_for(name, content = nil, options = {}, &block)
  if request.wiselinks?
    if block_given?
      options = content if content
      content = capture(&block)
    end
    content
  else
    content_for name, content, options, &block
  end
end
```